# Transformation and matrices

Tags: matrices, transformation

> Two sequences $y_t$ and $z_t $ satisfy
>
> $$y_t = ay_{t-1} + bz_{t-1}$$
>   $$z_t = cy_{t-1} + dz_{t-1}$$
>
> Where $a = 6$, $b = -20$, $c = -17$ and $d = -12$. From the two given equations above, a second-order difference equation of the following form can be derived:
>   $$y_{t+1} + ny_t + ry_{t-1} = 0$$
>   Where $n$ and $r$ are constants. The auxiliary equation
>   $$m^2+nm+r=0$$
>   Has two solutions $m=h$ and $m=k$ where $h>k$. To 2 decimal places, what is the value of h?

From the statement, I tried to find the value of H , however about the results. can someone help me?

Two sequences are given:

First from the first equation we express zt-1

Then we replace t-1 with t:

And finally we put the last two equations into the second equation:

After rearranging we get:

We multiply everything by -20 and rearrange:

So n = 6 and r = -412.
Hence the auxiliary equation is

Solving this quadratic equation we get two answers for m:
m =17.52 and m = -23.52
Since h>k the value of h is 17.52.
 Am I right?

Comment: Here is the time to learn latex.

Comment: Sorry typo error, does anyone know how to get value of H? from the pic?

Comment: for "First from the first equation we express zt-1", you mean $z_{t-1}$ or $zt - 1$?

Answer (score 0):

you can write this as matrix equation $$x_{n+1} = \pmatrix{6&-20\\-17&-12}x_n = Ax_n. $$ the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-3 \pm \sqrt{421}=17.518, -23.518$

so the value of $h$ is $17.518$